# Ajax tooltip doesn't disappear if mouse moves too fast

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a tooltip loaded with ajax for each item on my webpage. When you move the mouse too fast, it doesn't take the mouseleave event into account. Then, I tried to load the tooltip content with the page. However, there are a lot of contents so it takes four more seconds to load :/

What can I do?

Here is my jquery code :

```
$('.main').on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        var id = $(this).parent().data('candy');
        if(id != 0){ 
            $.ajax({
                url: 'tooltip.php',
                type: 'get',
                data: { 'type': 'candy', 'item_id': id },
                global : false,
                success: function(data){
                    $('.candyTooltip').html(data);
                    $('.candyTooltip .layer_item').show();
                }
            });
        }
    },
    mouseleave : function(){
        $('.candyTooltip .layer_item').hide();
    }
}, '.candy');
```

Also, I don't know if it's relevant but the SQL query takes 1,2ms and the PHP script takes 3,94ms.

Comment: Off he top of my head, in addition to hiding the tip when the mouse leaves the control, I would also set a time and hid it automatically after 5-10 seconds. That way it will hide at some point anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it !!!

All I had to do was put the ajax request inside a variable and abort it on mouseleave.

So, now it looks like this :

```
$('.main').on({
  mouseenter: function(){
      var id = $(this).parent().data('candy');
      if(id != 0){ 
         query = $.ajax({
              url: 'tooltip.php',
              type: 'get',
              data: { 'type': 'candy', 'item_id': id },
              global : false,
              success: function(data){
                  $('.candyTooltip').html(data);
                  $('.candyTooltip .layer_item').show();
              }
          });
      }
  },
  mouseleave : function(){
      if (query) { query.abort(); }
      $('.candyTooltip .layer_item').hide();
  }
}, '.candy');
```